# Laravel 9 testing is not performed after project clone from GIT

Tags: php, laravel, testing, tdd

I have cloned a project from GIT for the purpose of learning Test Driven Development. But as soon as i am run command php artisan test . It shows me the following error.

Test directory "/home/azzamumer/VIX-Investree-Fullstack-Franky-main/./tests/Feature" not found

Still unable to identify why i am receiving this error and how to resolve it.

Comment: Do you run `composer install`?

Comment: Yes, I ran it but the problem was not there.
The problem was that the cloned project doesn't have a Feature test by default and that's why it was showing error.
The error was resolved by running command
php artisan make:test UserTest
It then creates a feature test and then the tests were OK to run.